# Django NORel Fixtures

Tags: python, django, mongodb, fixtures

Is it possible to construct fixtures for a Django instance using a norel backend?  I'm currently running mongodb (via mongoengine) and running into errors stating "Invalid model identifier:" when trying to run syncdb with a fixture set up.

I am not setting up mongo in my settings.py, but rather setting up my models.py using mongoengine.

Thanks.

Comment: How are you setting up your models using mongoengine without setting it up as your backend in your settings? Are you just doing completely custom model classes that use mongoengine directly and not the django ORM?

Answer (score 1):

I believe most of the django management commands that do database operations expect to use the django ORM, assuming you have a database backend specified.

The `loaddata` command for loading in fixtures is probably no exception. Same as how you cannot make much use of the `syncdb` command if you are not using the database backend and django ORM. It has to introspect your models and assume they all subclass the django Model base class. You would most likely get errors if you were syncing completely custom non-django model classes.

What you might need to do is to look into writing your own management commands:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Answer (score 0):

For mongoengine you can use this: https://github.com/klen/mixer